# Ошибка сборки проекта Maven из нескольких модулей

Tags: java, maven, сборка, dependency-injection

Есть проект из нескольких модулей. Один из модулей состоит всего лишь из одного класса с константами. Данный модуль состоящий из одного класса, является зависимостью другого модуля. Для наглядности: модуль 1 (common-rabbitmq) является зависимостью для модуля 2 (dispatcher).
Когда я запускаю команду mvn package в корне проекта, он пытается собрать все оба модуля, но естественно при сборке 1 модуля с одним лишь файлом, выдает ошибку:

> invalid target release: 11 -> [Help 1]

Главный pom.xml проекта, это по сути родитель, в котором нету папки src и так далее, это просто parent:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>ru.test</groupId>
    <artifactId>testapp</artifactId>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <modules>
        <module>common-rabbitmq</module>
        <module>dispatcher</module>
    </modules>

    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>11</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>11</maven.compiler.target>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.12</version>
    </parent>

</project>
```

pom.xml модуля 1(common-rabbitmq), это модуль, в котором один java класс, где static final String описаны названия очередей для брокера:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <parent>
        <groupId>ru.test</groupId>
        <artifactId>testapp</artifactId>
        <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <artifactId>common-rabbitmq</artifactId>

    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>11</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>11</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>

</project>
```

pom.xml модуля 2 (dispatcher), это уже модуль с какой то логикой, в которой используются названия очередей из модуля 1 (common-rabbitmq):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <parent>
        <groupId>ru.test</groupId>
        <artifactId>testapp</artifactId>
        <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>

    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <artifactId>dispatcher</artifactId>

    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>11</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>11</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-amqp</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>biz.comfortvpn</groupId>
            <artifactId>common-rabbitmq</artifactId>
            <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
        </dependency>
   </dependencies>

</project>
```

ожидаю, что находясь в корне проекта, запустив команду mvn package получу jar файл модуля dispatcher, но получаю ошибку:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.10.1:compile (default-compile) on project common-rabbitmq: Fatal error co
mpiling: invalid target release: 11 -> [Help 1]
```

Вопроса два - как это решается? Почему при нажатии зеленой кнопки run в IDEA все работает, а при сборке мавеном нет?

Comment: Запустите сначала `mvn -v` и посмотрите какая версия Java используется - скорее всего не 11, а 8 или еще старее. Задайте мавену корректную версию Java (11 или выше) и все заработает